# hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files with DDL on local disk file system

Tags: hibernate, import, ddl

In my project all the database imports was on the classpath of the project, for example:

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/sqlite/initial_scenary.sql,/sqlite/escenarios.sql,</prop>
```

Now we want to add DDL in a file stored in C:/

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/sqlite/initial_scenary.sql,/sqlite/escenarios.sql,/C:\directory\distribucion\sentencias.sql</prop>
```

I have tired with:

- `C:\directory\distribucion\sentencias.sql`
- `/C:\directory\distribucion\sentencias.sql`
- `file:///C:\directory\distribucion\sentencias.sql`

And Hibernate don't do the import.

What can I do?

Comment: Just add local disk file system folder to the runtime classpath and then treat it the same way as usual.

Comment: Not working, can you give me an example? Thanks!